# Concerning Octrees

Tags: performance, quadtree, voxel, octree

I am creating a Minecraft like terrain engine thing, and I was wondering what exactly octrees are. With my engine I have seperated each part of it into chunks or regions - which from what I have read has something to do with it. Also, I was wondering if indices do increase performance within a game and if so how much? Any other ideas/ways to increase performance would be much appreciated. Note that I have already included backface culling and that if the box or a side is hidden don't show that side.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree Tada! And what do you mean by "if indices do increase performance within a game"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read this excellent article on FlipCode](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Introduction_To_Octrees.shtml)

Googleing for Octree and flipcode or Gamedev.net will give you a lot of references.

Thoughts on performance are hard to give because a lot depends on what you are doing. (how many changes are being made to the 'world', are there any objects moving, what do you want to use the Octree for (visibility, collision detection, rendering, ...) Read about [K-d-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) too because they might be more appropriate for your problem.

Comment: Well, yes the octrees are to be used for visibilty and rendering. And wow that link is really quite a great one thanks! So I think i must of alreadly implymented an octree without knowing it as my terrain is seperated into regions which have a size of 16*128*16, like minecraft, and I only show the regions in the viewing fustrum! :) Thanks!